# rasterio.open() giving parsedpath or unparsedpath error

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, arcgis-server, geoprocessing-service, rasterio

I am using rasterio to get elevation values from a raster. I am using arcpy module and rasterio module and I have published this script as a geoprocessing service.
I am able to run it properly as a standalone script but when I try to run it as a geoprocessing service through rest endpoint, I get the below error

> ValueError: path must be a ParsedPath or UnparsedPath object.

Also when I restart this service, it runs properly for the first time, but the next time i run the service, it gives me the same error. The code block where I am getting the error is as follows:

```
 def findElevation(start_siteLon, start_siteLat, bearingAngle, distance, rasterData, **kwargs):
        rasterData = r"D:\PAN_India.tif"
        start_siteLon = round(start_siteLon, 6)
        start_siteLat = round(start_siteLat, 6)
        geoLocations = []

        try:
            bufferDistance = kwargs['bufferDistance']
        except KeyError:
            bufferDistance = 0.03

        try:
            if kwargs['distanceUnit'] == 'km':
                distance *= 1000
                bufferDistance *= 1000
        except KeyError:
            pass

        for dist in np.arange(0, (distance + 0.000001), bufferDistance):
            geoLocations.append(list(findPoint(start_siteLon, start_siteLat, bearingAngle, dist)))

        arcpy.AddMessage("GeoLocations: {0}".format(geoLocations))
        elevations = []

        ## Here I get the error after rasterio.open(rasterData):- ValueError:path must be a ParsedPath or UnparsedPath object.
        with rasterio.open(rasterData) as src:

            try:
                elevVals = src.sample(geoLocations)
                for values in elevVals:
                    elevations.append(values[0])
            except IndexError:
                return None


        try:
            if kwargs['outputElevationUnit'] == 'km':
                elevations = [i / 1000 for i in elevations]
        except KeyError:
            pass

        return elevations
```

I get the error at rasterio.open().

I have
python2.7
rasterio 1.0.23

Comment: I suggest you to print the `rasterData` var in your code after you define it to check whether publishing the GP service has changed it or not (it shouldn't if you shared it exactly as you showed). But it might be that you're passing `rasterio.open()` somwthing different than `r"D:\PAN_India.tif"`. Just a guess though.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @umbe1987
IN the first run after restarting the GP service I get the following response
 GeoLocations: [[77.102166, 30.984845], [77.102226, 30.98458]]
esriJobMessageTypeInformative: D:\Pan_India.tif

In the next run
GeoLocations: [[77.102166, 30.984845], [77.102226, 30.98458]]
esriJobMessageTypeInformative: D:\NFS\CR793\PanIndia.tif
esriJobMessageTypeWarning: path must be a ParsedPath or UnparsedPath object 0 sec

Comment: Does `D:\NFS\CR793\PanIndia.tif` exist? Otherwise, you found your error.

Comment: Sorry, it is a typo, the location of the raster file is  D:\Pan_India.tif only

Comment: mmm, don't know. Is the folder/file readable by the arcgis user who's running the GP service?

Comment: I am positive that it is accessible by the arcgis user, since all the other  file gdbs and sde connections are all located in the same folder.  And it is able to run successfully at the first instance after restart.

Comment: I suggest you to have a look at the server log. It is in the ArcGIS Server manager site -> Logs (at least in recent versions).

Comment: Rasterio doesnt seem to work in a server environment as I am still stuck with the issue. However I came up with an alternative way of using arcgis spatial analyst module to determine the elevation values, But i really hope hat the rasterio issue gets resolved, since it is a pretty useful  open source alternative to arcgis spatial analyst.
Thanks for the help.